# Where do I put .txt and header files for xCode 5.1 c compiler

Tags: c, xcode

I've just started working with x code, till now I had been using tutorials point online c compiler (which suddenly isn't working anymore). Problem is I have no idea where to put my header and .txt files, I've followed a number of online tutorials. but they all say to different things and non of them work.

one problem is there is almost no tutorials to show for xcode 5, all of them seem to be xcode 4.

any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about header files you define?

Comment: Headers must be put in a location where the compiler can find them. That is something like 1. a predefined path, 2. the list of standard include paths, 3. your own list of include paths, and finally 4. in the same folder as where your source file is stored. None of this is relevant to .TXT files.

Answer (score 3):

Your header files should be placed in the same directory as your source files in order for the compiler to find them.

And it doesn't matter where your .txt files are, since the compiler doesn't care about those.

Comment: Well not *exactly* the same folder. A syntax `#include "my_includes/test/wot.h"` is perfectly okay.